# Prioritize threads.

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

So my application has a collection of Points. Each point has a CheckStatusTimer, CheckNewDataTimer, and CheckDevceTimer (They are System.Timers). 
A Point has a sampleTime property. If sample time is set to 30 seconds then:

```
CheckStatusTimer.Interval = sampleTime/4;   // ~7 seconds, it will reset and start over
CheckNewDataTimer.Interval = sampleTime/2;  // 15 seconds, it will reset and start over
CheckDevceTimer.Interval = sampleTime;      // 30 seconds, it will reset and start over
```

All those timers will trigger a function that will pull data from a connected (Modbus tcp) device and that takes some time. As you can imagine the more points i add the more threads will be scheduled and the process time for user calls will increase.

i create a task to process user incoming messages.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.ProccessMessage(session, value));
```

I have tried to set (i know is bad idea)

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

but that didn work, and also tried to

```
    var worker = new Thread(() = this.ProccessMessage(session, value))
                     {
                         Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
                     };
    worker.Start();
```

It didn't work as well, There were not differences on the processes times.
So my question is how can i prioritize a thread or the this.ProccessMessage(session, value) method, over the timers threads/methods. So when a user makes a call it would respond right away with no delay regardless of the size of my collection.

Comment: Don't prioritize threads, prioritize work.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Let's say you have 100 points, each with a 30 second sample time, then you would have 200 timers, with 100 x (4 + 2 + 1) = 700 events firing every 30 seconds. Which of those events are you trying to prioritize? Just keep in mind that prioritize means to make one task faster by slowing down another task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need queues here. One high priority queue and one low priority queue. All your timer threads should post to low priority queue. User messages should go to high priority queue. And to process these queues you can have a pool of threads reading the queue and processing the data, processing high priority queue first. This approach might work for your problem.